# Upload Image from Post Request to Cloud function

Tags: request, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way that the image that is uploaded by the user be directly sent to cloud function without converting to string in Python?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the image to the Cloud Function, it's better if the image has been uploaded to GCS. This way, you can just provide the gsUri and the Cloud Function can handle the image file by using the cloud storage client library. For example, [the OCR Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr) follows this approach.

In this case, if a function fails then the image is preserved in Cloud Storage. By using a background function when the image is uploaded, you can follow the strategy for [retrying background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) to have an "at-least-once" delivery.

If you want to use HTTP Functions instead, then the only recommended way to provide the image is by converting it to string and send it inline with the POST. Note that for production environments is way better to either have the file within the same platform or send it inline.

Comment: Cloud Functions have a limit on how large a multipart-body request can be

Comment: Hi @Neri thanks for your response. I have a constraint to not store the information. Even if I convert it to string or bytes, there is a JSON decoding issue which is failing during run time.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the JSON decoding issue?